# Swagger Code generation issue for array datatype in yaml spec

Tags: java, rest, yaml, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have set up OpenApi code generation in Java which accepts YAML as input and generates all the model code. As part of generating validating specific annotation, for one of the fields which is an array, and has a validation constraint which says Max item in the array is 7 and Max 70 text (which means the minimum length is 1 and maximum length is 70).
When the code is generated, only `@Size(max=7)` is generated but not `@Size(min=1,max=70)`. How do I handle this situation, I wanted to handle both validations. Also, is there an issue in the way Swagger generates the code?

**Yaml Specification Schema extract**

**Array [ 249 ]
    address_details [
    maxItems: 7
    Max70Text      string
    minLength: 1
    maxLength: 70]**

Generated Java code from OpenApi generator, notice that, from the below code `@Size(min=1,max=70)` is not generated automatically.

```
@Size(max=7) 
  public List<String> getAddressLine() {
    return addressLine;
  }
```

Comment: can you add the exact yaml that defines the array and show it correctly formatted?

Comment: @Mark the YAML that I'm using is confidential doc for my Employer. It's a valid yaml, I was able generate the code successfully but only a specific constraint for array is not considered.

Comment: Also, If the datatype is not array then MinLength and MaxLength is generated successfully but for array data type, only the MaxItem (maximum items that an array can hold) is generated but not the minimum and maximum length of each item added to an array. Note- Each array item has String datatype.

Comment: Please open an issue with the details via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Issue%3A+Bug&template=bug_report.md&title=%5BBUG%5D+Description and we'll look into it.